# How to return a copy of an object instead of a reference in actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, reference, copy

Imagine I have an object called "image", now I want to create multiply copies of this image to display it multiple times and with different properties. When I do image2 = image;, only the reference is copied and I thus still change the properties of the first object.

So, how to return a copy of an object instead of a reference in actionscript 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a more generic solution, take a look at this:

http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showpost.php?p=1897368&postcount;=77

Comment: Nice, any idea how to make it retain class association?

Comment: Looking into this, mate. This is also relevant to the previous asset loading class question I've answered for you a couple of weeks ago. Will update this post when I'm done playing. It should be possible, tho.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this post](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/03/duplicating-images-using-the-bitmap-and-bitmapdata-classes/).

Answer (score 1):

Create a `clone` method in the class. [This post](http://blog.comtaste.com/2007/10/improving_object_copy.html) mentions at the end how to do this for BitmapData, which you'll probably need for an image.